# How to avoid spaces before parenthesis in DisplayFormula cells?

Tags: formatting, stylesheet, display

When I write a formula in a DisplayFormula or DisplayFormulaNumbered cell, I like to use "traditional notation", i.e. function-parenthesis-argument instead of function-squarebracket-argument. However, Mathematica then always puts empty space between the two:

[image: example of the problem]

and the space gets even bigger when I use indices:

[image: another example of the problem]

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to select (at the right margin) the cell with the formula, go to Menu/Cell/ConvertTo/TraditionalForm. Take care to type `f[x]`, rather than `f(x)`.

Another way would be to use JournalArticle StyleSheet, rather than the Default one.